# Creating a pointer to the first value of a matrix

Tags: c++, matrix

I am trying to create a pointer to the start of a matrix to pass into a function as an argument. Here's what I have:

```
int **p;
p = &(&matrix[0][0]);
func(p);
```

In doing this though I get the error "lvalue required as unary '&' operand." I'm guessing it's just an issue of me not having the right syntax, but maybe not. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @perreal depending on how p is declared, it might not even compile.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, `matrix[0]` points to the start of the matrix (although itself is not a pointer, but an array). So the following should do it:

```
int* = matrix[0];
```

Comment: I don't think matrix[0] is even accessible this way. Have you tried? Maybe &matrix[0][0]. But then, he'll have to treat the matrix as an array inside the function. Or cast it. But if you're going to cast to some invalid type, just cast to void * then.

Comment: Well, then I guess I have to study more. It doesn't make much sense to me, though. If matrix[0] is an int*, matrix is an int**. And it's not. I mean, it's just my prejudice...

Comment: Please, not again. An array is **NOT** a pointer to the first element. It can *decay* into a pointer to the first element but they are **not** the same. `sizeof( matrix[0] ) != sizeof( &matrix[0][0] )`...

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas so `matrix[0]` doesn't point to the first element?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: In some contexts, it will decay and point to the same element, but they are not the same. Run the `sizeof` test, or try calling `template <typename T, std::size_t N> void f( T (&array)[N] ) {}` with `&matrix[0][0]` or an `int*`. In those two examples you can verify that they *type* of `matrix[0]` is not `int*`. The code in the answer is right, but the *text* is wrong, and a common source of confusion.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas I know they're not the same. But I don't see how `matrix[0]` doesn't always point to the start of the matrix. Maybe the wording is off, this is what I meant by pointer (points to something), not the actual type.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas oh okay, I agree on that, I should have been more careful.

Comment: Still not *correct*, but at the least it is not claiming that `matrix[0]` is a pointer (only that it *points* :)). There is a very thin line there... `matrix[0]` (as an entity) is an array, but when used as an *rvalue-expression* decays (is transformed by the compiler) into a pointer to the first element

Answer (score 2):

matrix[0][0] is an int, so it's address is &matrix[0][0].  What you want is

```
p = &matrix[0][0];
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function should expect a int [][SIZE] or a int *[SIZE] parameter for this to work.
Since C matrixes are linearized, they can't be handled like pointers to pointers.